# asp.net 5 mvc 6 loginUrl change path

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

When creating a new project in VS 2015 WebApplication, how would you go about changing the Redirect LoginUrl Path when not Authorize'd?

I have created a new Area, where I have created a loginController. This loginController requires you are Authorize'd. But when trying to reach the pages, I am redirected to "/Account/Login".

How would I go about changing this path to "/AREA/Login/Index"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try doing the following:

```
services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/<YOUR-AREA>/Account/Login");
});
```

Question: Did you decorate your controller with an `[Area]` attribute?

Comment: Hi,This worked perfectly. Thank you for the input! ANd yes, it was decorated with an area input.

Answer (score 12):

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options =>
{
    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = "/Login";
});
```

Comment: This worked for me when the accepted answer didn't. Perhaps the starter template has changed since that answer was posted.

Answer (score 5):

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = "/Login";
});
```

This is basically the same as Jhonattan's answer, and it worked for me when the accepted answer didn't.  The only difference is that if you don't have an `ApplicationRole` model, you can use `IdentityRole` (which `ApplicationRole` would inherit from).

Answer (score 0):

```
services.ConfigureIdentityApplicationCookie(options => {
  options.LoginPath = "/AREA/Login/Index";
});
```