# Default Login Location is not overridden in ASP.NET 5 MVC6

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following HomeController

```
[Area("Admin")]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

I have moved the Account section to its own area called Admin.

In ASP.NET 4 to change the default login location, one would change the web.config.

However in ASP.NET 5 I understand you have to do this in the Startup.cs as indicated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917659/asp-net-5-mvc-6-loginurl-change-path) answer

At the bottom of my Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){

...

    services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(options =>
    {
         options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Admin/Account/Login");
    });
```

However when run my Application `/Home/Index` it redirect to

> http://localhost:59693/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F

and not like the `Admin` Area like I explicitly specified.

Why is it not working

Comment: Do you have Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) in your startup? What is inside? Here is official cookie example: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/samples/CookieSample/Startup.cs

Comment: Yes, I have that section, it is the same as the ASP.5 RC1 template in Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 ASP.NET 5 new template

Comment: Show your `Web.Config`

Comment: Can you try set options.AutomaticChallenge = true explicitly?