# Decorating class with Authorize assumes Office 365 login, instead of offering choice

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have configured my .NET Core app to allow authorization either through Office 365 (Open ID) or Google.   If I go to the login page it shows both buttons and allows me to login using those.

But if I decorate a Controller Class with [Authorize] it sends me directly to our Office 365 login page instead of the page where they can select how they want to login.   How do I get it to send the user to the login page instead so they can choose the method they want to use (Office 365, Google, Facebook, Twitter)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [asp.net 5 mvc 6 loginUrl change path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917659/asp-net-5-mvc-6-loginurl-change-path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to set `OpenIdConnectOptions.AutomaticChallenge = false;`. It defaults to `true` because OIDC is more commonly used as the sole provider. It needs to be `false` if you want to have a login page where you choose between providers.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the same result in the latest update you should set:

```
 app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive
```